# javascript Amcharts adding listeners

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have two functions like this:

```
    function zoomChart() {
        chart.zoomToIndexes(0, 20000);
    }

    function zoomAtStartToLast90() {
        var dataLength = am_chartData.length;
        chart.zoomToIndexes(dataLength - 90, dataLength - 1);
    }
```

When I draw the chart at the beginning, I want to see last 90 records. So I need to call for `zoomAtStartToLast90()` function, but when I make an update on chart I want to see all 20k records, so I will call for `zoomChart()`.

inside  `AmCharts.ready(function () {` I call this: `chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);`

But where can I call `zoomAtStartToLast90()` function ? If I add it to addListener, chart is zoomed to last 90 records. Is it possible to call some function just after creeating chart ?

Comment: to trigger a function just after creating chat you can use `init` event.. http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmChart#init

Comment: Can you write this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to trigger a function just after creating chat you can use init event..

REF: [AMcharts Docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmChart#init)

Comment: do you have an example?